# Get the Value after `/` from Variable

Tags: javascript, url, pathname

I was trying to get the current page `pathname` using javascript. I was able to get it, but I'm getting it with the *Forward Slash* `/`. I'd want to remove that `/` from variable.

Here's the code which I tried. :)

```js
var URLPath = window.location.pathname;
alert(URLPath);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/slice) or [`substr`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substr) to get a substring starting from the second character:

```js
var URLPath = window.location.pathname.slice(1);
//                                    ^^^^^^^^^
alert(URLPath);
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
var URLPath = window.location.pathname;
alert(URLPath.substr(1));
```